# Error while trying to install in AWS Ubuntu Instance

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, aws, ubuntu

I have properly setup Magento 2.3.4 in my localhost. But whenever I try to deploy this to AWS Uuntu Instance I get the following error.

```
[ERROR] Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Area code is not set in /opt/alogic/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php:153
Stack trace:
```

[image]

I have gone through several questions here but haven't found any proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

When You Setup on Your Install Magento 2.3.4 . I have seen You have installing third Party Extention. so You can deselect third Party Extention While Installing Magento.After Installation Complete You can Enabled ThirdParty Extention and check it.